# How to disable Cash On Delivery on specific product type

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery, store-credit

Basically I need to disable cash on delivery on specific product type.
Basically i m using store credit of mage store. This is for wallet in magento.
on payment option its showing cash on delivery . its a not a physical or virtual product. So i need to disable cash on delivery on this product type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by [`Magento Event/Observer`](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)

First,using `payment_method_is_active` disable on depends current quote product type.

Code for this:

### Module config.xml code:

```
<global>
    <events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
        <observers>
            <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>yourmodel/observer</class>
            <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
            </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
        </observers>
    </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</global>
```

### Observer code is:

> ```
> <?php
>
> class YOURNANESPACE_YOURMODULE_Model_Observer {
>
>     public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
>         /* call get payment method */
>         $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
>
>         /*   get  Quote  */
>         $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
>
>         $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
>         if (empty($quote) || (null === $quote)) {
>             return $this;
>         }
>
>         /* Disable Your payment method for   adminStore */
>         if ($method->getCode() == 'YOUR_PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE') {
>             foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
>                 // get Cart item product Type //
>                 if ($item->getProductType() == 'YourProductType'):
>                     $result->isAvailable = false;
>                 endif;
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: just 2 min ahed gr8 work dude @amit

Comment: @Amit Bera how to get product type here

Comment: @DeepakRai,already code has been put.use $item->getProductType() for get Item product type

Answer (score 4):

for that you need to use magento `payment_method_is_active` event

I am assuming you know how to develop magento extension[If not then please check [this answer you get whole module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011348/disable-payment-options-only-cash-on-delivery-for-particular-product-magento)
Write this code in your `config.xml` from `app>code>codepool>namespace>package>etc`

```
<global>
    ...
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>PaymentFilter_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
    ...
</global>
```

Create observer file `app/code/codepool>namespace>package/Model/Observer.php`

```
class namespace_package_Model_Observer {

        public function paymentMethodIsActive(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
            $event           = $observer->getEvent();
            $method          = $event->getMethodInstance();
            $result          = $event->getResult();
            $currencyCode    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();


                if($someTrueConditionGoesHere){
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                }else{
                    $result->isAvailable = false;
                }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Can i get help here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/301777/57334 @Keyur Shah

Answer (score 1):

Have you look this I think this would bee solve your issue you just need to modify the methods.phtml file andfrom where you can got any quotes info and do the validations or conditions as well from the module by event - observer or by the modification in phtml file ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819037/disable-cash-on-delivery-for-specific-products

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011348/disable-payment-options-only-cash-on-delivery-for-particular-product-magento