# display error message if cash on delivery is not available

Tags: php, payment-methods, cash-on-delivery

we are using the following cashondelivery.php : http://pastebin.com/iD28fF2F

```
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cashondelivery.php
```

here we restricted only some zip codes for allowing cash on delivery payment method, means what zip codes we entered in following file,

if we enter those zip codes than only `cash on delivery` payment method will display,

if we enter other zip codes `cash on delivery` payment method will not display . but we have to

display the error message "cash on delivery is not available"

how we can achieve this....

Comment: There is a setting in admin to display error message if particular method is not available. Have you tried there ?

Comment: actually COD payment method is available only for some zip codes

Comment: Yes, but when you return false, Magento should be able to display that error message if you have enabled that.

Comment: than i iwll try now.....

Comment: @Prateek please let me know if you know any settings so that we can display that message.....

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**We can not say this is the write way but it might be work for you.**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

You can replace your methods.phtml code with below code.

```
<?php
$methods = $this->getMethods();
$oneMethod = count($methods) <= 1;

$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$restrictedZips = array('560043', '641006');
$address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
$customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
?>

<?php if (empty($methods)): ?>
    <dt>
    <?php echo $this->__('No Payment Methods') ?>
    </dt>
    <?php
else:
    foreach ($methods as $_method):
        $_code = $_method->getCode();
        ?>
        <dt id="dt_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
        <?php if (!$oneMethod): ?>

            <?php if ($_code == 'cashondelivery' && !in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)): ?>

            <?php else: ?>        
                <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if ($this->getSelectedMethodCode() == $_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
            <?php endif; ?>    

        <?php else: ?>

            <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>

            <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($_code == 'cashondelivery' && !in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)): ?>
            <label style="color: red;"><?php echo $this->__('cash on delivery is not available'); ?>   </label>
        <?php else: ?> 
            <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
        <?php endif; ?>

        </dt>
        <?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
            <dd id="dd_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
                <?php echo $html; ?>
            </dd>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;
?>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('additional'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('scripts'); ?>
    payment.init();
<?php if (is_string($oneMethod)): ?>
        payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');
<?php endif; ?>
    //]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, I confused with shipping method error messages.

To achieve what you are trying, you will need to override block **Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container** and change method `getMethods()` so that it includes not available COD method.

Then you'll need to change the template file checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml for your custom error message. There you'll need to check for COD and then if it's available for checkout.

Answer (score 1):

Require to check quote by using ***!empty($quote)*** to prevent error

please try this:

> ```
>   public function isAvailable($quote = null)
>     {
>          $restrictedZips = array('641004','641006');
>
>
>         if(parent::isAvailable($quote) && !empty($quote)):
>             $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
>             $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
>              if (in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
>                 return true;
>             }
>             return  false;
>         endif;
>        return  false;      
>     }
> ```

### Additional:

Instead do code at core class.It will be ***better idea to use Magento Event/Observer***.

**For your case use:** `payment_method_is_active`  event

**See an example** is  [How to disable Cash On Delivey on specific product type](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/67985/4564).

Just change at code of observer.

> ```
> <?php
> class YOURNANESPACE_YOURMODULE_Model_Observer {
>
>     public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
>     /* call get payment method */
>     $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
>
>     /*   get  Quote  */
>     $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
>     $restrictedZips = array('641004','641006');   
>
>     if($method->getCode()=='cashondelivery' ){
>
>       if(!empty($quote)):
>             $address = $quote->isVirtual() ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();
>             $customerZip = $address->getPostcode();
>              if (in_array($customerZip, $restrictedZips)) {
>                return $result->isAvailable= true;
>             }
>              return $result->isAvailable=  false;
>            endif;  
>         }
>    return $result->isAvailable=false  
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: i will try this...

Comment: where i have place " cod is not avaialble " text

Comment: This  is not possible for this code..In magento, payment method avaiable only check by true /false

Comment: but amit, i want to display the error message " cod is not available for this zip code" , i restricted the zip codes by using this file : http://pastebin.com/iD28fF2F

Comment: soory for this case , i cannot help you...

Comment: May be use `Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('cod is not available for this zip code.'));` but not sure 100%

Comment: please infrom where i need to add the above code

Comment: Just above  return  false;