# Disable purchase of online e-gift card upon code selection

Tags: magento-1.9, cash-on-delivery, gift-card

Dears, how can I disable the purchase of Online `e-gift card` once the end user selects the method of payment as: **CASH ON DELIVERY?**
 I don't want to let the users purchase an **Online E-GIFT card** and make the payment upon delivery.

Comment: I think you should disable COD for `e-gift card` products.

Comment: how can i do that? is it at level gift card as simple product and change it or system configuration?

Comment: Any updates please?

Comment: Hello @Marcos, AFAIK, It can be handle at the coding level. have you tried Vishwas's answer ?

Comment: HELLO dear, yes I'm ready for the coding level, but i didn't found this path: app/code/Company/Module/etc/ also inside the xml file i couldn't find this path for the instance instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" , so can you support please?  my path and template are as follows: public_html/app/etc/modules and  public_html/app/design/frontend/tv_arion_package/tv_arion

Comment: Hello @Marcos, You can put module directly at `public_html` folder.Please see my answer.

Comment: Hello @Marcos, did you try my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create events.xml file under app/code/Company/Module/etc/. Then write “payment_method_is_active” event in it. This is the event which hits on checkout page for payment method availability.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now create PaymentMethodAvailable.php under Company/Module/Observer/ and write following code in the file. I am disabling the CASH ON DELIVERY payment method when there is gift card in your cart (You can get the CheckoutSession and check if there is any gift card in cart)

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
    $giftCardFlag = false;
    if(//checkforcondition if giftCard in cart) {
     $giftCardFlag = true;
   }

        // you can replace "checkmo" with your required payment method code
        if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="youPaymentCode" && giftCardFlag) {
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
}
```

Now the payment method CASH ON DELIVERY is disabled from checkout page .

Comment: can't we have a simple answer? in addition, can i disable some products in my store to have the checkout selected with COD payment?

Comment: any updates please?

Comment: Simpler in which way, this is best implementation that i can think of

Comment: Hello dear, yes I'm ready for the coding level, but i didn't found this path: app/code/Company/Module/etc/ also inside the XML file i couldn't find this path for the instance instance="Company\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" , so can you support please? my path and template are as follows: public_html/app/etc/modules and public_html/app/design/frontend/tv_arion_package/tv_arion

Comment: please can you help me finding the path?

Comment: you need to create these files , you won't find these paths @Marcos

Comment: yes i tried it but didn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

We are going to create a simple module say `Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod`

Create following files:

> app/etc/modules/Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Pawan/FilterPaymentMethod/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <filterpaymentmethod>
                <class>Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod_Model</class>
            </filterpaymentmethod>
        </models>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                        <class>filterpaymentmethod/observer</class>
                        <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
                    </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Pawan/FilterPaymentMethod/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
    $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

    $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();

    if($method->getCode()=='cashondelivery' ){ // payment method code
            foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                if($item->getProductType()=='simple')://check product type
                    $result->isAvailable = false;
                endif;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

- After create module, You need to flush cache
- You need to change Product type.
- This file and directory will not available by default, you need to create all of them
- You can [Download](https://pawan.info/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Pawan_FilterPaymentMethod_0.0.1.zip) module from here.
- [Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67982/how-to-disable-cash-on-delivery-on-specific-product-type/67987#67987)